# Typescript : A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically generate the columns of a grid. ( react-data-table-component ).

Here is an example of how to define the column.

```
  const columns = [
{
  name: 'Title',
  selector: (row: { title: any; }) => row.title,
},
{
  name: 'Year',
  selector: (row: { year: any; }) => row.year,
},];
```

I would like to do the same dynamically from an Array ( API Fetch ).

```
    const data = ["Title", "Year"];
    const columns = data.map((element) => ({
      name: element.toLowerCase(),
      selector: (row: { [element.toLowerCase()]: any; }) => row[element],
    }));
    
    console.log(columns)
```

This code does not work, I keep having this error :

[element.toLowerCase()] =>

`A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)`

row[element] =>

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)`

Comment: Well you can't run JS code inside the TS type system so `{[element.toLowerCase()]: any}` is not a type; you could make `{[k: string]: any}`. Do you care about `columns` being more strongly typed than `{ name: string; selector: (row: {[k: string]: any}) => any; }[]`? Can you show a [mre] of how you will use `columns` in the dynamic case and what code you'd like to succeed/fail? Depending on your use cases this could range from trivial (just use the type mentioned above) to impossible (as it would require full existential types which TS lacks), and without more info it's hard to know which.

Comment: I don't care but how can I dynamically define my column like that ? UC : https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/iframe.html?id=getting-started-examples--page&viewMode=docs#basic-sorting

Comment: Let me try a different way: if you write `{ [k: string]: any; }` instead of `{[element.toLowerCase()]: any}`, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` array is type of `string[]` in this code. If you want to use the elements of that array as types, you must type cast it with `as const` so that the values are literal types instead of `string`.

`const data = ["Title", "Year"] as const;`

#### Full example:

```
const data = ["Title", "Year"] as const;
const columns = data.map((element) => ({
  name: element.toLowerCase(),
  selector: (row: { [key in typeof element]: any; }) => row[element],
}));
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works like a charm. I still need to understand this part : `key in typeof element` but I'm going to figure it out :)

Comment: Since you casted your array `as const` now each element became a literal type in that array. So when you are mapping over columns, each `element` gets its type from the array values. In your context it's either `Title` type or `Year` type. So when you are typing the keys of your `row` object, you basically are referring back to the type of element, which can either be `Title` or `Year`. That way, it doesn't error when you use `element` as the key of `row`.